# Haproxy set backend server via query string

Tags: haproxy

I am using sticky sessions for stateful requests to our backend servers. Haproxy sets the cookie and the setup works well. I now want the option to set the required backend server via a query string for testing and clients which can't use cookies.

Both of these curls should go to the same backend:

```
curl mysite.com -I --cookie "serverid=app-2"
curl mysite.com?serverid=app-2 -I
```

I have tried many combination of config to no avail.

```
backend myapp

  cookie      serverid insert indirect nocache

  stick-table type string len 32 size 1M

  stick on cookie(serverid)
  stick on url_param(serverid)

  server app-0 111.111.111.111:80 cookie app-0
  server app-1 222.222.222.222:80 cookie app-1
  server app-2 333.333.333.333:80 cookie app-2
```

Is it possible todo this in haproxy?

Comment: Does the client always send the `serverid` cookie/url_param?

Comment: Yes there is always one of them set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, it's possible.

Stick tables enable a client-server persistance, but they don't define *which* server a given client ends up on. That's what the `cookie` directive does (in combination with the `cookie` option to the `server` directives).

Unfortunately, if your client doesn't support cookies, it's not of much use.

The way to get around that is by having a set of `use-server` lines to catch those cases. These are processed before, and have precedence over, the cookie routing, so that if a `use-server` matches, it will be used.

Given your request that the two `curl` commands mentioned in the question end up on the same box, this config works for me in my testing (very minimal though it may have been).

```
backend myapp

  cookie serverid insert indirect nocache

  use-server app-0 if { urlp(serverid) -i app-0 }
  use-server app-1 if { urlp(serverid) -i app-1 }
  use-server app-2 if { urlp(serverid) -i app-2 }

  server app-0 142.135.221.205:10001 cookie app-0
  server app-1 142.135.221.205:10002 cookie app-1
  server app-2 142.135.221.205:10003 cookie app-2
```

If you have more than 3 servers, it's going to get a little unwieldy, but it's currently the only way I can see making it work the way you need.