# HAProxy override backend cookie using query parameter

Tags: haproxy

Based on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/777764/363770), I can successfully override the backend with a query parameter:

```
backend servers
  balance roundrobin
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  use-server web1 if { urlp(SERVERID) -i web1 }
  use-server web2 if { urlp(SERVERID) -i web2 }
  server web1 web1-internal:80 check cookie web1
  server web2 web2-internal:80 check cookie web2
```

However, I would like for this to "persist" in subsequent requests; i.e. I want a new Set-Cookie with the value from the query parameter to overwrite any existing SERVERID cookies. HAProxy doesn't add a Set-Cookie if the request came in with a valid SERVERID Cookie. Removing the `indirect` option didn't work.

Is the only solution to use `preserve` and have the backend always respond with Set-Cookie, or is there a way to do this in HAProxy?

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but I suspect that you could just statically set the cookie with `rspadd` in the frontend, using the url's server ID, effectively spoofing the backend's own cookie for cases that you want.

Comment: @GregL Surprisingly, HAProxy is removing the cookie, whether I put the following in the frontend or the backend: `http-response add-header Set-Cookie SERVERID=%s;\ path=/`

Comment: I think you might need to wrap the `%s` in something to tell HAproxy it that it's a token from the log format, but I can't find anything about it in the docs.

Comment: Your other option would be to just use the capture pattern that you're using in the backend  to set the cookie `http-response add-header Set-Cookie SERVERID=%[urlp(SERVERID)];\ path=/` (not tested).

Comment: @GregL I'm getting "'http-response' : sample fetch <urlp(SERVERID)> may not be reliably used here because it needs 'HTTP request headers' which is not available here." I tried in both frontend and backend and I also tried urlp_val. Actually, %s worked fine. If I changed the cookie name to SERVERID1 then I could see the right server every time; however, if it matches the `cookie` name, then HAProxy removed it. It seems I'm bumping into some internal logic. I think I'll just go with the `preserve` option and set the cookie in my backends. Thanks for the try though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by creating new backends that set the SERVERID cookie and routing to them via frontend directives.

```
frontend http_in
  acl set_current_site_cookie urlp(current_site) true
  acl set_snapshot_site_cookie urlp(snapshot_site) true

  bind *:80
  use_backend set_current_site_cookie if set_current_site_cookie
  use_backend set_snapshot_site_cookie if set_snapshot_site_cookie
  default_backend servers

backend set_current_site_cookie
  cookie SERVERID insert
  server current_site server.com:80 cookie current_site

backend set_snapshot_site_cookie
  cookie SERVERID insert
  server snapshot_site snapshot-server:80 cookie snapshot_site

backend servers
  cookie SERVERID insert indirect nocache
  server current_site server.com:80 cookie current_site weight 50
  server snapshot_site snapshot-server:80 cookie snapshot_site weight 50
```

We use this for staged rollouts, setting the weight in the `servers` backend to 0, and then testing using the query param `current_site=true`.